# Theano: Using theano.scan with theano.scan_module.until

Tags: python, while-loop, theano

I'm new to using `theano.scan` and `theano.scan_module.until`. From the docs [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html#theano.scan), I'm not sure how to set variables in my `while` loop, and I'm uncertain how to adapt this post [here](http://theano-users.narkive.com/cCNzuH3M/is-scan-module-until-more-like-while-or-do-while#post2) to use `theano.scan_module.until`.

This is the code I'd like to translate to equivalent theano. Someone wanna take a shot in translating this? (And perhaps explaining the translated code.)

```
# Code to perform a random walk using a row stochastic matrix M.
for i in range(100):
    r_last = r
    r = r.dot(M)
    err = np.linalg.norm(r - r_last, ord=1).sum()
    if err < N * tol:
        break
```

I see three assignment operations here, and one if-statement. But I don't know how to translate this to theano.

And if you were curious, you could paste this code above to set the variables

```
import numpy as np

N = 3
tol = 1.0e-6
M = np.random.rand(N, N)
M = M / M.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)

r = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float) / N
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
N = 3
tol = 1.0e-6
```

You can define your symbolic function like this:

```
r_init = T.vector()
W = T.matrix()

def step(r):
    r_prime = T.dot(r, W)
    delta = (r_prime - r).norm(1)
    condition = T.lt(delta, N * tol)
    return r_prime, theano.scan_module.until(condition)

outputs, updates = theano.scan(step, outputs_info=[r_init], n_steps=1024)
r_final = outputs[-1]

solve = theano.function(inputs=[r_init, W], outputs=r_final)
```

And then use it like this:

```
M = np.random.rand(N, N)
M /= M.sum(axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))

r = np.ones(N, dtype=np.float) / N

print solve(r, M)
```

By the way, you are not performing a "random walk."  You are solving for r such that rW = r, typically called the stationary distribution of the Markov chain.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I suggested some edits, do the edits look correct? (The code runs after I make those edits.) Also, I called it a "random walk" because `M` can represent the transition probabilities on a system with 3 nodes. But yes, the system will converge to the stationary distribution of the Markov chain.

Comment: @hlin117 I don't see any suggested edits.  What changes did you have to make?

Comment: Just rewrote the edits, let's hope stackoverflow remembers them!

Comment: @hlin117 Yes the `r_final = outputs[-1]` line had a bug.  Glad it works for you now.